# Reject phone number with all same digits in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to reject phone numbers that have all the same digits.

Example: `222-222-2222` or `333-333-3333`

I tried stupidly looping through all the characters, but that was a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test if a string contains only one distinct digit character (plus potentially arbitrary many non-digit characters), you can use:

```
function areAllDigitsTheSame(phoneNumber) {
    return /^\D*(\d)(?:\D*|\1)*$/.test(phoneNumber);
}
```

To test if a string matches the exact pattern `###-###-####` with all digits being the same, you can use:

```
function areAllDigitsTheSame(phoneNumber) {
    return /^(\d)\1\1-\1\1\1-\1\1\1\1$/.test(phoneNumber);
}
```

In both cases, the key point is that the `()` notation in a regex "captures" what it matches and makes it available for a back-reference (`\1`) to specify that it matches only an identical substring.

Comment: can you please tell how to build the regex which is opposite to   /^\D*(\d)(?:\D*|\1)*$/ . This one passes if the number has same digits. I want one which prevents a number with same digits

Comment: @ZaveedAbbasi: The best approach is to use the "not" feature of whatever language you're using; e.g., in JavaScript, `! /^\D*(\d)(?:\D*|\1)*$/.test(phoneNumber)`. But if you *need* this functionality to be inside the regex, then you can use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): change `^...$` to `^(?!...$)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!(\d)\1+(?:-\1+){2}$)\d+(-\d+){2}$
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qW6mJ0)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match the exact pattern

```
var str = '222-222-2222';
allowed(str); // false, console log bad

var str = '123-456-7890';
allowed(str); // true, console log good

function allowed(n) {

  if (/(\d)\1{2}-\1{3}-\1{4}/.test(n)) { console.log('bad'); return false; }
  console.log('good');
  return true;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4x4m/)

Good luck
:)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
function AllSameDigits(str) {
    return /^(\d)\1+$/.test(str.replace(/[^\d]/g,''));
}

str='222-222-2222';
alert(AllSameDigits(str));
```

This strips out all non-digit characters, then asks: does the string start with a digit and consist of only the same digit repeated some number of times?

Answer (score 0):

you need to first remove the hiphens and then check your number with this :

```
^(\d)\1+$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/iJ2aB0